# unable to configure nginx try_files correctly for files in subfolder

Tags: nginx

Trying to configure nginx to find files from subfolder. Code from nginx documentation:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
```

- request "/" opens file index.html - it's ok
- request "/folder" opens file /folder/index.html - ok
- but request "/folder/file" as I suggest, should open /folder/file.html - but it returns 404

Please help me configure nginx try_files setting correctly so nginx can find file.html in "folder" directory when "/folder/file" request is received

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `try_files` statement. Are you certain that the `/path/to/root/folder/file.html` is readable by `nginx`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is, it opens by direct link http://www.my-domain.com/folder/file.html

Comment: Is there another `location` statement that is processing requests to this folder?

Comment: Well, of course! And one of them contain no try_files setting. Thank you for tip, Richard.